# Java cannot be accessed error from outside package error

Tags: java, sigar

CpuPerc() is not public in CpuPerc; cannot be accessed from outside package

...

```
import org.hyperic.sigar.*;
import org.hyperic.sigar.Cpu;
import org.hyperic.sigar.CpuPerc;

/**
 *
 * @author John
 */

public class GetCpu {
    public void Start() {
            Sigar sigar = new Sigar();
            CpuPerc perc = new CpuPerc();
            System.out.println(getCpuPerc()); // error appears here

    }
}
```

What is this error and how can I fix it. I am using SIGAR API.

Comment: What part of the error message don't you understand? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html

Comment: @SLaks none of it really, its quite new to me. You seem to know more about this then me, so can you please help me out?

Answer (score 1):

The error message is telling you that instances `CpuPerc` were not intended to be obtained this way ([package-private constructor](https://github.com/hyperic/sigar/blob/master/bindings/java/src/org/hyperic/sigar/CpuPerc.java)). [`getCpuPerc`](http://www.hyperic.com/support/docs/sigar/org/hyperic/sigar/Sigar.html#getCpuPerc%28%29) is an instance method of `Sigar` which returns the required instance.

```
Sigar sigar = new Sigar();
CpuPerc perc = sigar.getCpuPerc();
System.out.println(perc.getCpuPerc());
```